# Does the WP theme of a penalized site hurt my SEO?

Tags: wordpress, seo

There is this really nice premium WordPress theme for affiliate sites. It comes with lots of handy features so it would be ideal. However, I am worried that plenty of dodgy affiliate sites have used it in the past and ultimately got penalized by Google.

**Question**: Would such *history* of penalties harm the SEO of my site in any way?

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen any indication that Google would penalize a user based on a theme.

Exceptions to that might include if a theme uses some shady CDN to host files on it, but otherwise Google will not know (or care) about your theme.